# Forma correcta de maquetar una tabla con 2 bucles uno en el <TH> y otro en el <TD>

Tags: html5, angularjs

Tengo la siguiente tabla, he conseguido que se maquete bien pero he tenido que repetir el bucle por cada elemento del array.

```
<table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th> ID </th>
            <th> Fecha </th>
            <th> ID de las Posiciones </th>
            <th> Nombre de las Posiciones </th>
            <th> Descripciones de las Posiciones Descripcion </th>
            <th> Fecha de las posiciones</th>
            <th> Usuario de la posicion</th>
            <th> </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let ObjetoA of listaDeObjetosA">
            <td> {{ ObjetoA.id }}</td>
            <td> {{ ObjetoA.fecha | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy' }} </td>
            <td>
                <tr *ngFor="let arrayB of ObjetoA.listaDeArraysB">
                    <td> {{ arrayB.id }} </td>
                </tr>
            </td>
            <td>
            <tr *ngFor="let arrayB of ObjetoA.listaDeArraysB">
                <td> {{ arrayB.nombre}} </td>
            </tr>
            </td>
            <td>
                <tr *ngFor="let arrayB of ObjetoA.listaDeArraysB">
                    <td> {{ arrayB.descripcion }} </td>
                </tr>
            </td>
            <td>
                <tr *ngFor="let arrayB of ObjetoA.listaDeArraysB">
                    <td> {{ arrayB.fecha}} </td>
                </tr>
            </td>
            <td>
                <tr *ngFor="let arrayB of ObjetoA.listaDeArraysB">
                    <td> {{ arrayB.usuario}} </td>
                </tr>
            </td>
            <td>
                BOTON
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Me ha funcionado pero veo muy feo hacer el `*ngFor="let arrayB of ObjetoA.listaDeArraysB"` por cada elemento pero no se me ha ocurrido nada más. Visualmente queda bien pero no es lo óptimo.

Añado https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ygkamp

ID  Fecha deberian estar en la misma altura que el resto de celdas

Comment: Si esa página desaparece en el futuro, esta pregunta no le va a servir a los que vengan con el mismo problema. Para este caso (la apariencia), trata de incluir una captura de pantalla.

Comment: Esta el Codigo. Quien busque en el futuro esta pregunta vera la respuesta ha la tabla que inserte y lo entenderá si alguien lo resuelve. Gracias por tu comentario y ayuda.